# Is Node.js required for a PeerJS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, peerjs

How are Node.js and PeerJS related? Is Node.js required for a PeerJS application? The peerJS site does not specify anything about Node.js but it has been mentioned everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only intention is to use peerjs client from your webpage, you don't need node.js.

Signup for peerJS cloud API key. Use it in your client.

If you dont want to use the peerjs cloud server , and want to setup your own peerjs server, you would need node.js .